# How to fix weight in bayesan average

Tags: bayesian, mean

I am reading the article of wikipedia about [bayesian average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average). This seems very interesting about on developing rating systems, but I have a doubt. How to fix the weight C of the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of "Bayesian average", but the calculation is equivalent to having a Gaussian *prior belief* having mean $m$ and precision $C$.  Choose your prior based on information you already have.

Comment: Precision in the sense of inverse of the variance or the inverse of the standard deviation?

Comment: @emanuele http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(statistics)